# Scala: write a MapReduce progam to find a word that follows a word [Homework]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I have a homework assignment where I must write a MapReduce program in Scala to find, for ***each word*** in the file which word that follows the most.

For example, for the word "basketball", the word "is" comes next 5 times, "has" 2 times, and "court" 1 time.

In a text file this might show up as:

basketball is..... (this sequence happens 5 times)
basketball has..... (this sequence happens 2 times)
basketball court.... (this sequence happens 1 time)

I am having a hard time conceptually figuring out how to do this.

The idea I have had but have not been able to successfully implement is

Iterate through each word, if the word is basketball, take the next word and add it to a map. Reduce by key, and sort from highest to lowest.

Unfortunately I do not know how to take the next next word in a list of words.

For example, i would like to do something like this

```
    val lines = spark.textFile("basketball_words_only.txt") // process lines in file

    // split into individual words
    val words = lines.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))

    var listBuff = new ListBuffer[String]() // a list Buffer to hold each following word

    val it = Iterator(words)  

    while (it.hasNext) {
      listBuff += it.next().next() // <-- this is what I would like to do    
    }

    val follows = listBuff.map(word => (word, 1))
    val count = follows.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y) // another issue as I cannot reduceByKey with a listBuffer

    val sort = count.sortBy(_._2,false,1)

    val result2 = sort.collect()

    for (i <- 0 to result2.length - 1) {
     printf("%s follows %d times\n", result1(2)._1, result2(i)._2);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. If I am over thinking this I am open to different ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using MLlib's sliding function:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

val resRDD = textFile.
  flatMap(_.split("""[\s,.;:!?]+""")).
  sliding(2).
  map{ case Array(x, y) => ((x, y), 1) }.
  reduceByKey(_ + _).
  map{ case ((x, y), c) => (x, y, c) }.
  sortBy( z => (z._1, z._3, z._2), false )
```